# Print out only the first card of the card deck

Tags: python

Basic card deck creation with a shuffle. I still have to finish coding the proper strings to display `Jack, Queen etc`, but that's not the problem.

It's printing the first card which is exactly what I want. However, there is a runtime error because the Card class doesn't have the attribute `cards`. The `cards` list belongs to the `Deck` class. But somehow it's still printing though. How is it still printing?

What is the correct way of printing only the first card?

```
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.val = val

    def display(self):
        print(f"{self.val} of {self.suit}")
        print(self.cards[0])


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    # Display all cards in the deck
    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card.display())

    # Generate 52 cards
    def build(self):
        for suit in ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades']:
            for val in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, val))

    # Shuffle the deck
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
deck.show()
```

Output:

```
12 of Spades
AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'cards'
```

Comment: Everything that is printed **before** the error is raised will be printed with no problem. BTW your code doesn't print or output anything, there is no running code, just definitions

Comment: I don't understand you by `How is it still printing?` what do you mean? the error raised after your print.

Comment: Remove `print(self.cards[0])` from `display` method.It is a method of `Card` class, and this class knows nothing of `cards`. You should define a method, say `displayfirst`, in `Deck`.

Comment: you should write display first card method in `Deck` class

Comment: Well a `Card` object doesn't have a `cards` attribute. What did you expect this line to do? Anyway it doesn't make much sense that a `Card` object will have a list of all cards... That should be the `Deck`'s job...

Comment: Again, because the error is on the `print(self.cards[0])` line. The line before that (`print(f"{self.val} of {self.suit}")`) works fine

Comment: I recommend you running this code in [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit). It will help you follow and understand what's going on in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called the `display` method of `Card` class. In that method you are printing `cards[0]` value which is not available in `Card` class.

To print the first card of the deck after shuffling, pass the position to `show` method of `Deck` class.

I have updated the `display` method of `Card` class and `show` method of `Deck` class.

```
import random


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.val = val

    def display(self):
        return f"{self.val} of {self.suit}"


class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    # Display all cards or a single card at a position
    def show(self, pos=None):
        if pos != None:
            print(self.cards[pos].display())
        else:
            for card in self.cards:
                print(card.display())


    # Generate 52 cards
    def build(self):
        for suit in ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades']:
            for val in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, val))

    # Shuffle the deck
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    deck.show(0) # call deck.show() to show all cards
```

Output:

```
8 of Diamonds
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. I was going to create a separate function but this is boss.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work. I've add the show_first method which show only the first card off the deck.

```
import random 

class Card(object): 
    def __init__(self, suit, val): 
        self.suit = suit 
        self.val = val 

    def display(self):      
        print(f"{self.val} of {self.suit}")

class Deck(object): 

    def __init__(self): 
        self.cards = [] 
        self.build() 

    # Display all cards in the deck 
    def show(self): 
        for card in self.cards:        
            # Make sure to pass the deck
            # object to the display.
            # No need to print beacause the display function does it 
            card.display(self) 

    # Show the first card of the deck
    def show_first(self):
        self.cards[0].display()

    # Generate 52 cards 
    def build(self):
        for suit in ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades']: 
            for val in range(1, 14):      
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, val)) 

    # Shuffle the deck 
    def shuffle(self): 
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1): 
            r = random.randint(0,1) 
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
deck.show_first()
```

Comment: Very elegant. Thank you Lucino.  Upvoted. I knew the Cards class did not have the cards list but it was still getting printed correctly so it was confusing me.

Comment: Lucino. If `print(self.cards[0])` was an error, why was python still printing only the first element correctly?  I was getting correct printing plus the error at the same time. This would not happen in Swift or Obj-C.

Comment: Because in python you can add property at runtime. So python assume that the cards property is going to exists when you call the function.

Comment: Ok. I have to be careful about that. p.s. Is this line correct? `print(card.display())`. I am using your new `display` method but I'm getting an error. Maybe it's in my function call `deck.show()` is still printing all of them.

Comment: Make sure to pass the deck to the display function: `card.display(self)`

Comment: self being in that case the deck object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214150/discussion-between-edison-and-lucino772).